# Scheme Function that takes n and list, and return list n

Tags: scheme

I tried many ways to solve my assignment but the problem is I guess I miss something or I used something in a wrong way :

my : 
solution

```
 (define (return l)  
 (cond ((null? l) '())         
 ( cond (!= (mod n (car l) 0) )  
 ;; here will check if not equal 0 so it is not
 return then I will     remove it from the list 
 ((eq? n (car l) )  
(return (cdr l)) )        
 (else (cons (car l) (n (cdr l)))) 
  )   
 (return n (cdr l) ) ;;if not return then I will keep it in the list 
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to solve this would be to use `filter`, as it already does what you want:

```
(define (divisibleByN n lst)
  (filter (lambda (e) (zero? (modulo e n))) lst))
```

If that's not an acceptable solution, we can use the standard template for traversing a list and building an output list:

```
(define (divisibleByN n lst)
        ; base case: if the list is empty, return the empty list
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        ; if the current number is divisible by n
        ((zero? (modulo (car lst) n))
        ; add it to output list and advance recursion
         (cons (car lst) (divisibleByN n (cdr lst))))
        ; otherwise just advance recursion
        (else (divisibleByN n (cdr lst)))))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(divisibleByN 3 '(5 9 27 14))
=> '(9 27)    
(divisibleByN 4 '(15 6))
=> '() 
(divisibleByN 7 '())
=> ()    
(divisibleByN 5 '(40 40 40 3 10 50))
=> '(40 40 10 50)
```

Comment: @hisae if this post helped you, please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, just click on the check mark to its left ;)